# rsync include only subdirectory

Tags: files, rsync, backup

at the moment I am struggling to find a solution to include only files in a subdirectory but exclude all other stuff. File structure looks like this

```
$ tree ../
../
├── from
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── aa
│   │   │   └── x.txt
│   │   ├── a.txt
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── b
│       ├── b.txt
│       └── c.txt
└── to
```

and only the stuff in a/aa/ shall be transferred into to/.

```
$ rsync -avh --include=a/aa/*** --exclude=* ../from/ ../to/
```

does not work and to/ stays empty but doing this with a/

```
$ rsync -avh --include=a/*** --exclude=* ../from/ ../to/
```

it works

```
$ tree ../
..
├── from
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── aa
│   │   │   └── x.txt
│   │   ├── a.txt
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── b
│       ├── b.txt
│       └── c.txt
└── to
    └── a
        ├── aa
        │   └── x.txt
        ├── a.txt
        └── b.txt
```

but there a.txt and b.txt should not be there. What did I miss?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There might be a way to do that with `--include` and `--exclude`; I'm not sure. But wouldn't `mkdir -p ../to/aa/a && rsync -avh ../from/aa/a/ ../to/aa/a/` be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first command, `a/aa/***` would match `aa/` and anything after that, but there is no match for `a/`, so nothing is copied.

In the second command, `a/***` matches `a/` and anything after that, so you copy more than just `a/aa/` contents.

For example, this should be enough:

```
rsync -avh --include='/a/' --include='/a/aa/***' --exclude='*' from/ to/
```

`man rsync` to `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`